# microsoft graph api v1.0 endpoint does not support adding ReferenceAttachment

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, attachment

Different people have reported this using different languages but it can also be reproduced using the graph explorer.

This is a rather severe issue. Not only can I not use the v1.o endpoint, If I implement this against the beta endpoint I have no idea how long it will work. It puzzles me that I found other people reporting this (on the sdks instead of on the api) from over a year ago and is still not resolved. Perhaps not much used feature...

after creating a mail try to add a reference attachment. For the v1.0 endpoint this looks something like

[using v1.0 endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me%2Fmessages%2FAAMkAGNjYzU0ZmYzLTU0YTctNDg5MS1hMjVkLTViNjYxYjFjZjlmMQBGAAAAAABwW5owjozVQqPtxPt1rujcBwDe8PU95PVdS7TllxfIC7dIAAAAAAEPAADe8PU95PVdS7TllxfIC7dIAAK0I0GuAAA%3D%2Fattachments&method=POST&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com&requestBody=eyJjb250ZW50VHlwZSI6InB1dHNvbWV0aGluZ2hlcmUiLCJpc0ZvbGRlciI6ImZhbHNlIiwibmFtZSI6Im15ZmlsZW5hbWUudHh0IiwiQG9kYXRhLnR5cGUiOiIjbWljcm9zb2Z0LmdyYXBoLnJlZmVyZW5jZUF0dGFjaG1lbnQiLCJTb3VyY2VVcmwiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3JldC5zaGFyZXBvaW50LmNvbS9zaXRlcy9leHRlcm4vX2xheW91dHMvMTUvRG9jLmFzcHg/c291cmNlZG9jPSU3QkI1NzQxQjgzLUZFNkMtNDU5MC04MUJELUQ1NDVDMDVGRTc2QyU3RCZmaWxlPVNlY3JldGZpbGUuZG9jeCZhY3Rpb249ZGVmYXVsdCZtb2JpbGVyZWRpcmVjdD10cnVlIiwicHJvdmlkZXJUeXBlIjoib25lRHJpdmVCdXNpbmVzcyJ9)

if you execute this you get: a bad request [400] Note that the sourceUrl property does not even exist on the v1.0 resources (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/referenceattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0)

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
        "message": "The property 'SourceUrl' is required when creating the entity.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-01-08T16:52:31",
            "request-id": "2b8b4c2a-0f21-4691-bebc-574a30a9973a",
            "client-request-id": "c42b7a0f-b6cb-0d7a-b461-d6ac026067a4"
        }
    }
}
```

Executing against the beta endpoint is possible, that one does contain the SourceUrl property, among others that are not in v1.0. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/graph/api/resources/referenceattachment?view=graph-rest-beta)

[Try in graph explorer against beta endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me%2Fmessages%2FAAMkAGNjYzU0ZmYzLTU0YTctNDg5MS1hMjVkLTViNjYxYjFjZjlmMQBGAAAAAABwW5owjozVQqPtxPt1rujcBwDe8PU95PVdS7TllxfIC7dIAAAAAAEPAADe8PU95PVdS7TllxfIC7dIAAK0I0GuAAA%3D%2Fattachments&method=POST&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com&requestBody=eyJjb250ZW50VHlwZSI6InB1dHNvbWV0aGluZ2hlcmUiLCJpc0ZvbGRlciI6ImZhbHNlIiwibmFtZSI6Im15ZmlsZW5hbWUudHh0IiwiQG9kYXRhLnR5cGUiOiIjbWljcm9zb2Z0LmdyYXBoLnJlZmVyZW5jZUF0dGFjaG1lbnQiLCJTb3VyY2VVcmwiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3JldC5zaGFyZXBvaW50LmNvbS9zaXRlcy9leHRlcm4vX2xheW91dHMvMTUvRG9jLmFzcHg/c291cmNlZG9jPSU3QkI1NzQxQjgzLUZFNkMtNDU5MC04MUJELUQ1NDVDMDVGRTc2QyU3RCZmaWxlPVNlY3JldGZpbGUuZG9jeCZhY3Rpb249ZGVmYXVsdCZtb2JpbGVyZWRpcmVjdD10cnVlIiwicHJvdmlkZXJUeXBlIjoib25lRHJpdmVCdXNpbmVzcyJ9)

Comment: Do you see the issue only with Graph SDK and against v1.0 only?

Comment: @Dev

the issue arises when using the graph explorer, java sdk, and I found references to it on the .net sdk as well but did not verify but sounds more than plausible.

The issue indeed only arises against the v1.0 endpoint not the beta. I'm currently as a workaround using 2 different endpoints. the v1.0 for everything else and the beta for the reference attachment.

It is not a matter of sdks. It seems it is something in the endpoint implementation that is wrong. You can see this looking at the response.

There is no such thing as the 'SourceUrl' property  on v1.0

Comment: Yes i tested it against beta (graph explorer) and its works. I am yet to test it with v1.0 or sdk :)

Comment: @dev Did you had the chance to test the v1 endpoint?